# firebase rest api equalto search fails if have a + (plus) symbol in the query

Tags: firebase

I am querying by the firebase rest API trying to find a specific record. Indexes are all setup ok.

Basically if I do a query like the following it wont find any records (the records do exist):

```
https://<firbeaseapp>.firebaseio.com/users.json?auth=<authcode>&orderBy="email"&equalTo="user+test1@nowhere.com"
```

The above call just returns an empty record set.

If I am searching for records without the + symbol it all works fine. Do I need to encode the + symbol or something?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a URL encoding issue. A `+` in the URL represents a space, not a plus. You need to URL encode all values used in your parameters. Assuming Javascript:

```
var emailEncoded = encodeURIComponent('user+test1@nowhere.com');
var url = 'https://<firbeaseapp>.firebaseio.com/users.json?auth=<authcode>&orderBy="email"&equalTo="' + emailEncoded + '"'
```

Comment: Thanks @Kato. I did have a go at this but it still doesnt seem to find the record. My API call became sonething like **https://<firbeaseapp>.firebaseio.com/users.json?auth=<authcode>&orderBy="email"&equalTo="user%2Btest1%40nowhere.com"**.  Do I need to store the values encoded in firebase?

Comment: What is the actual value in the database, what is unencoded and encoded lookup value? There's a lot of details you can track down here, including some sample code that recreates the issue.

Comment: I'm having the same problem using the REST API to query a value with a '+'  in it.  This returns nothing: `curl -X GET 'https://<firebaseapp>.firebaseio.com/users.json?orderBy="phoneNumber"&equalTo="+16171234568"'`, but when I run similar queries without the '+' on other fields in `users` I get a result.

Answer (score 1):

In your URL, substitute `+` with `\u002B`.  So:

```
https://<>.firebaseio.com/users.json?orderBy="email"&equalTo="user\u002Btest1@nowhere.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same issue - recording solution for posterity. The answer was to double URL-encode the plus sign, eg: ..&orderBy="test+data" -> ..orderBy="test%252Bdata"